# Получить из многомерного массива все ключи. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Пример многомерного массива:

```
array(1) {
  ["sitename.ru"]=>
  array(1) {
    [49396665029]=>
    array(1) {
      [29576565627]=>
      array(1) {
        [16776565626]=>
        array(1) {
          ["http://url.ru"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["ANSWERED"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["static"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["calls"]=>
                int(1)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Это где такие задания дают?

Comment: Такой ответ возвращает API Calltracking

Comment: while + is_array() + key()

Comment: и current() еще

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!)

Comment: можешь написать ответ и принять его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имхо, в предыдущем ответе все усложнено, можно же попроще

```
function get_array_keys_multi(array $array): array
{
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, get_array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

Ну, или..

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v,$k) use(&$result){
    $result[] = $k;
});

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение моей проблемы.

Comment: Зачем здесь рекурсия?

Comment: @Ипатьев, в чем трабл? Лично мне удобнее работать так. Пишите свои ответы без рекурсий.

Comment: трабл в иронии. "в предыдущем ответе все усложнено" :)

Comment: @Ипатьев че ты так до рекурсии докопался?) Иерархические данные в большинстве случаев обрабатываются с применением рекурсии. JSON кодируется/декодируется с помощью рекурсии в любой реализации потому что мы не знаем сколько может быть вложенностей и веток, а иначе как ты реализуешь это... То что советуешь ты не работает если есть разветвление

Comment: @Mamba да рекурсия здесь не при чем. просто надо иногда голову включать, а не шпарить по шаблону "вложенный массив? рекурсия!".

Comment: @Mamba так-то деревья можно обходить и в глубину и в ширину.

Comment: @Ипатьев Эм...) Это даже смешно становится. Что значит "по шаблону", если ты шпаришь по шаблону - это очень большой плюс. Люди не просто так придумывали паттерны и т.д. Что же плохого в том, чтобы использовать всем знакомые алгоритмы и конструкции? Разве ни этого ты хочешь, когда читаешь чужой код?

Comment: @Ипатьев c точки зрения простоты и краткости кода `array_walk_recursive` будет оптимален.

Comment: @teran Понятно, но зачем, когда существует старушка рекурсия, как бы она не бывала коварна, но в подобных случаях, когда речь идет об апи и мы точно знаем, что оттуда не вернется 50 элементов, почему бы не воспользоваться локаничным вариантом?

Comment: @Mamba потому что рекурсия несколько дорогая в производительности конструкция, особенно если глубина большая может быть.

Comment: @teran Да ладно, ну тогда может посоветуете автору вообще писать свой веб сервер на C? А что, PHP это дорогая конструкция, 8 простых рекурсивных вызовов это же серъезно, автор полюбе хайлоад приложение пилит

Comment: @teran чтобы было понятно, оба этих ответа **абсолютно** бессмысленные. Их ценность в реальной жизни нулевая. Они написаны механически, без малейшего понимания зачем этот код вообще нужен. Они написаны из предположения что ключей на одном уровне может быть больше одного, но при этом пихают все ключи в одноранговый массив. То есть отличить потом, с какого уровня ключ, будет невозможно. То есть для той задачи, которую они себе сами придумали и якобы правильно решают, они неприменимы. Давай, вещай мне теперь про точку зрения простоты и краткости.

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка, твой ответ мне больше понравился(первый вариант). Буду его использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Имеете ввиду так?

```php
$in = array('key1'=>array('key2' => array('key3' => array('key4'=>1, 'key5' => 2))));


function get_keys_recursive($in) {
    $keys = array();
    $buff = array_keys($in);
    $keys = array_merge($keys, $buff);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        $key = $keys[$i];
        if(isset($in[$key]) && is_array($in[$key])) {
            $buff = get_keys_recursive($in[$key]);
            $keys = array_merge($keys, $buff);
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}

var_dump(get_keys_recursive($in));
```

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "key1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "key2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "key3"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "key4"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "key5"
}
```

Но зачем вам это не пойму, просто обращайтесь к необходимому элементу

```php
$data["sitename.ru"][49396665029][29576565627]
```

Comment: Зачем здесь рекурсия?

Comment: Идея хорошая, без рекурсии нельзя это сделать? "$data["sitename.ru"][49396665029][29576565627]" ключи меняются.

Comment: @Walther я ж тебе написал.

Comment: Спасибо за решение моей проблемы.

Comment: он тебя поблагодарил, а ты ему из зависти минус поставил. Фу таким быть

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи:

```
while(is_array($arr)){
 $arrayKeys[] = key($arr);
 $arr = current($arr);
}
```

Comment: ```php
$arr = array('key0'=>1, 'key1'=>array('key2' => array('key3' => array('key4'=>1, 'key5' => 2))));```
Агась.